# Can I extract my contacts from my device remotely

Tags: samsung

I lost my device which is a Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge can I extract my contacts and pictures from the device remotely

Answer (score 2):

If you saved your contacts as Google contacts, you can access them by visiting the [**Google contacts site**](https://contacts.google.com) and logging in with the account under which you saved those contacts, which will likely be the Google account associated with your device.

If you're unsure about whether you saved your contacts as Google contacts, you should check that site using the primary Google account you used on your device, and any other Google accounts associated with that device.

If you can't find them in your Google contacts, then, unless you set up some tool on your device beforehand specifically for this purpose, you will not be able to recover your contacts.